# PYTHON (PANDAS) Concatenate content of two rows on the last of these two rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm struggling on concatenations of content of two rows into the last of these two rows.

Here my situation:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | NaN | Rossi | Brambilla |
| Federico | Giovanni | Giorgio | Marcello |

I would like something like

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | NaN | Rossi | Brambilla |
| Federico | Giovanni | Rossi Giorgio | Brambilla Marcello |

Could you please help me to reach this result?

Thanks in advance!

I tried the following:

```
df.iloc[1] = df_bo.iloc[0] + " " + df_bo.iloc[1]
```

but it gives me the following

> IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

I tried to transpose DF too, but it's seems to be a bit sophisticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to get rid of the NaNs, then [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) to join the names:

```
df.iloc[1] = df.stack().groupby(level=1).agg(' '.join)
```

If you want to limit the input rows:

```
df.iloc[1] = df.iloc[:2].stack().groupby(level=1).agg(' '.join)
```

Output:

```
          A         B              C                   D
0       NaN       NaN          Rossi           Brambilla
1  Federico  Giovanni  Rossi Giorgio  Brambilla Marcello
```

Answer (score 0):

If the original dataframe is df, this should work. :)

```
df2 = pd.concat([df.iloc[:1, :], pd.DataFrame(df.T[0] + ' ' + df.T[1]).T])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.loc[1,["C","D"]]=df1.loc[:,["C","D"]].agg(" ".join).tolist()
df1
```

out

```
          A         B                    C                             D
0       NaN       NaN                Rossi                     Brambilla
1  Federico  Giovanni  Rossi Rossi Giorgio  Brambilla Brambilla Marcello
```